# JSONAPI Resource routes not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsonapi-resources

I am trying to use [JSONAPI Resource](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources) gem to create an API for my rails application. I want to be able to leverage normal rails routing with my controllers and have a namespaced API as well.

So far I have something like

```
# sitting in resources/api/goal_resource.rb
module Api
  class GoalResource < JSONAPI::Resource
    attributes :name, :description, :progress
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users,
    path: '',
  controllers: {
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    invitations: 'users/invitations',
    sessions: 'users/sessions'
  },
  path_names: {
    edit:  'settings/profile'
  }

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root 'dashboard#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root 'users/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end

  post '/invitation/:id/resend', to: 'users/invitations#resend', as: :resend_invitation

  resources :goals do
    resources :goal_comments
    resources :goal_followers, only: [:index]
    member do
      post :on_target, as: :on_target
    end
  end

  resources :users, path: '/settings/users', only: [:index, :update, :edit, :destroy]
  resources :teams, path: '/settings/teams', only: [:index, :new, :create, :update, :edit, :destroy]
  resources :notifications, only: [:index]

  get "my_goals", to: "my_goals#index", as: :my_goals
  get "user_goals/:user_id", to: "user_goals#index", as: :user_goals
  get "team_goals/:team_id", to: "team_goals#index", as: :team_goals

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    jsonapi_resources :goals
  end
end


# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.2'
gem 'jsonapi-resources'
# other gems here

# models/goal.rb
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  # some more code here
end
```

Is it possible to use this gem in conjunction with normal routing? What am I doing wrong? `rake routes` returns all the routes for my application, but no api routes.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason the `jsonapi_resources` is not working because you have to derive your `Application Controller` from `JSONAPI::ResourceController` as well:

```
class ApplicationController < JSONAPI::ResourceController
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

Another thing is (This is not causing your routes to disappear), use the plural of the resource in the route. Use `goals` like below NOT `goal`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # other routes here

  namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json' } do
    jsonapi_resources :goals
  end
end
```

Here is a [demo application](https://github.com/cerebris/peeps) that uses `jsonapi_resources`.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the jsonapi_resources gem cannot be run in conjunction with routes that are not related to an API. Is this correct? I am now getting errors for all my other routes in my application `JSONAPI: Could not find resource 'dashboard'. (Class DashboardResource not found)`. I have updated my routes so you can see what I mean. Note I don't want my dashboard to use jsonapi_resources.

Comment: Yeah, I think they are targeted for API only applications. And as you tested that it did not work. But, I am not 100% sure. Could not find any obvious source that tells it! But, looking at some of theit codes on gihtub, seems like they are targeted for API only applications.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working

```
# app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb
module Api
  class ApiController < JSONAPI::ResourceController
  end
end

# app/controllers/api/goals_controller.rb
module Api
  class GoalsController < ApiController
  end
end
```

I just created a separate `ApiController` and made that inherit from the `JSONAPI::ResourceController` then I created an additional controller for my goals.

My normal `controllers/goals_controller.rb` still works perfectly!